# How to parameterize sql query

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, database

How can I parameterize simple create table sql query?

```
CREATE TABLE `rmr_form` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Please help and explain. I'd really appreciate it. :(
Thanks guys!

Comment: you can simply build a dynamic sql and then run it.

Comment: table creates usually aren't parameterized since they're run once. Do you have some extreme use case to justify this extreme practice?

Comment: I have a form, then the data will be inserted to that table. Should insert query be parameterized?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with using proc.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_tabCreate]
        @tabName        nvarchar(30)
        AS
        BEGIN

        IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tabName) AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[@tabName]

DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX)
    Set @SQLString = 'CREATE TABLE ' +@tabName+
    '(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RankID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SlotTime] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [SlotDate] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]'

EXEC (@SQLString)
END
```

And switch field to params like a '@tabName'